# Add Project Reference to Unit test project in net.core RC2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

Not sure how to modify project.json file in unit test project project.
[image: 1]

I have two projects. One is asp.net web api project. The second one is the unit test project. I want to reference the first one in the second one.

The project json file is

```
{
 "version": "1.0.0-*",

 "dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
   "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
   "type": "platform"
},
 "xunit": "2.1.0",
 "dotnet-test-xunit": "1.0.0-rc2-build10025",

},
"testRunner": "xunit",
"frameworks": {
 "netcoreapp1.0": {
   "imports": [
     "dotnet5.6",
     "dnxcore50",
     "portable-net45+win8"
     ]
   }   
 } 
}
```

Not sure how to reference it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of the following:

- manually add your project name in "dependencies" section in project.json, like you add other nuget packages;
- use standard Visual Studio "Add reference" command and select project from solution. This will add record to project.json file automatically.

Answer (score 0):

did you try it like this:

```
{
 "version": "1.0.0-*",

 "dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
   "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
   "type": "platform"
},
 "xunit": "2.1.0",
 "dotnet-test-xunit": "1.0.0-rc2-build10025",
 "BTNValidation": "1.0.0-*"

},
"testRunner": "xunit",
"frameworks": {
 "netcoreapp1.0": {
   "imports": [
     "dotnet5.6",
     "dnxcore50",
     "portable-net45+win8"
     ]
   }   
 } 
}
```